# HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth not working debian lenny

Tags: bash, history

Can anybody confirm if by setting the the following env variables under debian lenny will make previous history entries not to be saved. GNU bash, version 3.2.39(1)-release

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
export HISTSIZE=500
```

I have added them to my `/etc/bash.bashrc` but I keep getting repeated commands.

Comment: Cross-posted at: http://superuser.com/questions/119204/histcontrolignoreboth-not-working-debian-lenny and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426119/histcontrolignoreboth-not-working-debian-lenny

Answer (score 3):

The options "ignoreboth" and "ignoredups" only prevent duplicates of the immediately preceding command from being added to the history. Earlier duplicates have no effect.

```
$ echo $HISTCONTROL
ignoreboth
$ echo a
a
$ echo b
b
$ echo b
b
$ echo a
a
$ history 4
1047  echo a
1048  echo b
1049  echo a
1050  history 4
```

As you can see `echo a` appears twice and `echo b` appears once.

You may be looking for the "erasedups" option.

```
$ echo $HISTCONTROL
ignoreboth:erasedups
$ echo c
c
$ echo d
d
$ echo d
d
$ echo c
c
$ history 4
1076  echo $HISTCONTROL
1077  echo c
1078  echo d
1079  history 4
```

Here both `echo c` and `echo d` appear only once.

Comment: erasedups is very usefull - thanks for pointing out!

Comment: that's just wonderfull...thx...

Answer (score 0):

Try using ignoredups intead of ignoreboth, add it to the /etc/profile file.

Answer (score 0):

To uniqely record every new command is tricky. First you need to add to
`~/.profile` or similar:

```
HISTCONTROL=erasedups
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -w'
```

Then you need to add to `~/.bash_logout`:

```
history -a
history -w
```